# tmux で選択範囲をコマンドに流し込みたい

Tags: tmux

tmux で emacs もしくは vi モードにて、範囲選択が可能ですが、この選択範囲をそのまま tmux が動いているサーバー上で、新しくコマンドを実行しながらその標準入力に、選択範囲の内容を流し込みたくなりました。

emacs でいうところの send-region に相当するようなことがやりたいと思っています。

このようなことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

tmux（や GNU Screen）の普通の使い方の話ですよね。
`copy-mode` 中は `M-w` (emacs) とか `Enter` (vi) とかで選択範囲をバッファに保存します。
`paste-buffer` (`ctrl-b` `]`) や `choose-buffer` (`ctrl-b` `=`) でバッファの中身を今の pane に流し込みます。

Comment: 投稿してから気付いたんですが emacs の `(send-region PROCESS START END) Send current contents of region as input to PROCESS.` 相当、ということで、プログラムを実行するときの話でしたね。

Comment: そうです、 tmux の buffer に保存したい、というわけではなく、何かしらのプロセスを起動して、そのプロセスの標準入力に region の中身を流しこみたい、がやりたいことです。